# Could we get embedded YouTube video?

Tags: feature-request, hyperlinks

In one of the SE sites I'm in, YouTube links are automatically converted to embedded YouTube videos in posts.  As an example, see [this question](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/22085/how-to-train-in-order-to-perform-a-good-drum-solo/22089#22089).

Could we get this feature added to Lifehacks?  I think it's important for certain "how to" questions like shoe lace tying.

Comment: You mean a plugin like shockwave flash? I don't see that many hacks are going to have a corresponding youtube vid.

Comment: The feature already exists in other SE sites so it's just a matter of switching it on.  At least two hacks I've already answered have YouTube links and I've only been on the site for two days.

Answer (score 14):

No. Not until many situations make this necessary. The solutions should be presented in text form. They may be accompanied by a video link but if we enable that feature we would invite answers that are just the video with no or too little information in the text.

That makes the stuff hard to search through.

Answer (score -1):

I think we should. I have used YouTube video even in two of my own answer ( [1](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/14885/how-to-protect-a-cd-without-a-case/14887#14887) and [2](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/14809/how-to-stop-books-closing-themselves/14819#14819)). We can ask stack-exchange to activate it for this site too like [Movies & TV](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/631/video-embedding-for-movies-se) did.

Answer (score -3):

I'd move to allow it rather than waiting for some "critical mass". Retroactive changes suck, and if providing a video legitimately improves the question, there's no reason to exclude it from the get-go.

That said, if a video is *all* that is provided, raise the pitchforks and downvote the answer to all hell. It's the identical problem with link-only answers:

- The external content could rot, so the answer can become completely useless
- The part relevant to the answer is maybe kinda sorta indirectly somewhere on the page, and without context, or couching in terms of the question, is useless.

Comment: We don't want to rely on embedded YouTube videos because we have no control over whether or not they are taken down. We want all needed information to be found *in the post itself* here, which means not relying on a video or image hosted somewhere else

Comment: @ZachSaucier you are reiterating what I said in my post and I agree wholeheartedly. Do you contend that a YouTube video would never be useful?

Comment: Not an embedded one, no. It would make users feel that they don't need to include the content from the video in the answer itself